# My docker container which is running inside AWS ElasticBeanstalk is not able to connect with the host

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ebs

My application runs on port 5000 and I have exposed the 5000 port in the docker file.

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
"services":
  "backend":
    "image": "<imageURL>"
    "ports":
      - "5000:8080"
```

Container port and application port: 5000
Server port: 8080
The security group of have also been configured properly and the application is able to connect with the database but not working as I try to ping that IP of the server.
My application has an ping API.

Comment: Does "5000":"8080" mean that your local EBS port 5000 is mapped to docker image's port 8080?

Comment: Ping will not work unless it is explicitly configured to do so for that instance.
https://serverfault.com/a/511740

Comment: @fly2matrix I think OP means that there's an API endpoint on their service called 'ping', rather than using ICMP ping.

Comment: Do you have those `ports:` backwards?  That would forward _host_ port 5000 to _container_ port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you referring to with EBS server as "EBS" is Elastic Block Storage, not the computing

If you're using AWS ECS you need to configure "PortMapping" to map external ports with the container ports

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_PortMapping.html

If you're using EC2 make sure that your have your service listening to all IPs using the netstat command

```
netstat -anlp | grep [your port]
```

and security group inbound and outbound rules are configured properly

Comment: tried using the command. `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26075/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      26080/docker-proxy`

Comment: ok then the application is listening to port 5000, it has to inbound config to a security group or subnet inbound ACL or your server is not assigned to public subnet